# Ошибка: функция засчитывает только первый знак

Tags: python, функции

Здравствуйте!

Делаю программу на Питоне, которая считает количество определенных знаков препинания в тексте. Столкнулся с проблемой: функция засчитывает только первый нужный знак на строчке, после чего сразу же переходит на другую - даже в том случае, если в оставшейся части строчки есть такие же знаки. В чем проблема?:(

```
punct=0 #счетчик

for a in line:

    if '.' in a:

        punct=punct + 1

print punct
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регексп

```
import re
text = "hello, mam \n hello, dead, it's very good"
pattern = re.compile('.*$', re.M) 
values = pattern.findall(text) # создает список строк
for value in values: # проверяет каждую строку
    print value.count(',') # считает количество запятых в строке
```

Comment: сложновато выходит. count проще.

Comment: Ну да, я подумал, что надо количество запятых в каждой строке.
Ну а если в предложение, то да надо text.count(',')

Answer (score 1):

у меня нет возможности комментирования, поэтому добавлю ответ (но это все же просто комментарий)
я вижу, вы только начинаете знакомство с языком, поэтому мой вам совет:

```
punct=punct + 1
```

вот эту штуку лучше переделать вот так

```
punct+=1
```

с вас не убудет, но код будет читабельней и солидней.

с уважением.

хотя подкину еще индусятины в этот топик (питон 3)

```
text.split(".")
count = len(text) + 1
```

всё так же с уважением.

Answer (score 0):

используй text.count(symbol)

Answer (score 0):

Не та команда. Он проверяет наличие в строке точки. Т.е. если она есть - срабатывает сложение. Всё. Если идти Вашим путём следует отрезать кусок строки вместе с нашедшейся точкой и повторить проверку в оставшемся куске... Хотя, конечно, это не оптимальный путь...

Answer (score 0):

исходя из текста задачи и кодом решения у автора самая обычная семантическая ошибка:
он проверяет вхождение символа в строку, а не сравнение всех символов как задумано..
следовательно код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
punct=0
for line in lines:
    for symbol in line:
        if symbol==".":
            punct+=1
print punct
```

или :

```
for symbol in bigtext:
    if .....
```

так же можно использовать кучу других более/менее гуманных способов =)